# how many threads Tomcat create if i dont define in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7

I just now installed Tomcat to serve dynamic contents and my apache for php to serve static contents.

while trying to do optimisation, I Was just looking into Server.xml and found below configuration.

```
<!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

**tomcatThreadPool** is commented and it is not used in connector so what it means to me is my tomcat is not considering above setup and not limiting the maxThreads = 150.

So just trying to understand if i keep setup as it is(commented executor) in server.xml then

1. How many max threads my tomcat will create.
2. and how many spare threads it will keep.

If any experienced tomcat admin could you please share some info.

Guys please dont guess, by looking at above config i can guess it my self.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default for the HTTP connector, `maxThreads` is 200 and `minSpareThreads` is 10. 
That is, unless an other value is specified or you are using a `Executor`.

See [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation) for detail.